# glfw pkg-config error when building a fyne app

Tags: go, fyne

Golang code:

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

func main() {
    application := app.New()
    window = application.NewWindow("Hello rohan")

    window.SetContent(widget.NewLabel("Hello again"))
    window.ShowAndRun()
}
```

When this code is executed, I get the following error.

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- gl gl
Package gl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gl' found
Package gl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gl' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
# fyne.io/fyne/vendor/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw
In file included from ./glfw/src/internal.h:188,
                 from ./glfw/src/context.c:30,
                 from ../../../go/src/fyne.io/fyne/vendor/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw/c_glfw.go:4:
./glfw/src/x11_platform.h:36:10: fatal error: X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h: No such file or directory
   36 | #include <X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Any solutions or advice on this issue would be much appreciated. P.S I am using Go version 1.13.8 and an ubuntu 20.04 WSL on windows.

After running `sudo apt-get install golang gcc libgl1-mesa-dev xorg-dev` command, I now get this error:

```
2020/12/21 12:12:19 PlatformError: X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing
panic: NotInitialized: The GLFW library is not initialized

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
fyne.io/fyne/vendor/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw.acceptError(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4332bd, 0x991100)
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/vendor/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw/error.go:174 +0x216
fyne.io/fyne/vendor/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw.panicError(...)
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/vendor/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw/error.go:185
fyne.io/fyne/vendor/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw.CreateStandardCursor(0x36001, 0x1)
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/vendor/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw/input.go:530 +0x4e
fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw.initCursors()
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw/window.go:35 +0x3c
fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw.(*gLDriver).initGLFW.func1()
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw/loop.go:76 +0x6b
sync.(*Once).doSlow(0x10de160, 0xc000068dc8)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/sync/once.go:66 +0xe3
sync.(*Once).Do(...)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/sync/once.go:57
fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw.(*gLDriver).initGLFW(0xc0000c00f0)
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw/loop.go:69 +0x65
fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw.(*gLDriver).createWindow.func1()
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw/window.go:1175 +0x56
fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw.runOnMain(0xc0000a5440)
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw/loop.go:51 +0xab
fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw.(*gLDriver).createWindow(0xc0000c00f0, 0x9b7b98, 0xb, 0xc000146001, 0xc000068f08, 0x85c288)
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw/window.go:1174 +0xd4
fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw.(*gLDriver).CreateWindow(0xc0000c00f0, 0x9b7b98, 0xb, 0xc000146000, 0xc0000c00f0)
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/internal/driver/glfw/window.go:1166 +0x44
fyne.io/fyne/app.(*fyneApp).NewWindow(0xc000146000, 0x9b7b98, 0xb, 0xc000146000, 0x0)
        /home/rohan/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/app/app.go:52 +0x47
main.main()
        /home/rohan/Code/Go/practice/main.go:10 +0x56
exit status 2
```

Hopefully, someone can help me on this, or give me any advice on how to solve it.

Comment: https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/355 may be the same issue, gl refers to same service here and in the issue. `apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`

Comment: Using WSL you will need to run an X server as well to be able to present GUI apps. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242

Really to build a Windows GUI app on Windows you should not use the Linux subsystem, as this will not build a true native app. Why not use the windows tooling and MSYS2, as shown on https://developer.fyne.io/started/

Answer (score 13):

Some Linux systems lack the compile headers for graphics libraries that are installed. Thankfully this is only needed for development - the apps will run without encountering this.

For Ubuntu or Debian try `sudo apt-get install golang gcc libgl1-mesa-dev xorg-dev`.
Installation varies per-platform, details at https://developer.fyne.io/started/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Linux Mint this helped:

```
    locate pkgconfig/gl.pc
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gl.pc

    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
```